# Java-PDF is saved but java see only old PDF

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, pdf

I have a problem with java. I wanna create PDF file using itextpdf in java spring. Next i wanna send this pdf using email. I run java application and i send email using REST API. My mail is sendin correctly but attachment is old PDF. It is mean that I make request from API and my pdf is created in java and send by email. My new pdf is created by java and i see this but by email java send old pdf which was generated before again run application.

It is my function to create PDF:

```
public static final String DEST = "src/main/resources/sample2.pdf";
    public void createPDF(User user) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph(user.getEmail()+"aaaaaa"));
    document.close();
}
```

It is my function to send:

```
public void sendResults(User user)
      throws MessagingException, FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    helper.setSubject("test");
    helper.setText("test");
    helper.setTo(user.getEmail());
    helper.setFrom("mail@gmail.com");
    helper.addAttachment("sample2.pdf", new 
    ClassPathResource("sample2.pdf"));
    emailSender.send(message);
}
```

I have two request: 
*create this PDF
and
*send mail with pdf

PDF is default save in folder "resources". Everything is great but despite that in java after request "create PDF" is new PDF, method "send mail" send old pdf :/ I do not know, what is wrong. Help  me.

Comment: How are you deploying the app? In general, you don't want to write data to inside the application--if it's a WAR file you can't anyway. Save it somewhere *outside* of the app.

Comment: If you just want to send this PDF immediately after generate it, you can save it to ByteArrayOutputStream and just hold it in memory if the PDF is light-weight.

Comment: It is app for my study and to learn. It will not be on production, so it is good solve for me, but this with save to ByteArrayOutputStream is very interesting. It is so fast as you write ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this method of loading a file from a resource folder in Java.

`ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("sample2.pdf").getFile());`

For spring based application you can take advantage of ResourceUtils class.

```
 File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:xyz.xml")
```

or add a field with annotation @Value to your bean:

```
 @Value("classpath:xyz.xml")
 private Resource resource;
```

And then simply:

```
 resource.getInputStream();
```